# Sending Bearer Token with HttpPost in Android

Tags: java, android, httpclient, restful-authentication

I couldn't find a way to authenticate my app with my server using the Bearer token I had created. it works perfectly with Postman though.

I've tried using UTF-8 encoding, using ?access_token in url, tried a lot of answers I found on Stackoverflow.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://dmyzda2o.ui.nabu.casa/api/services/script/turn_on");
//httpPost.addHeader("Accept-Language", "he");
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Authorization", "Bearer eyJ0NiJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJmOWVkZDI5YjY2MTE0Mjc3YNDdmMzIwMWI2ZCIsImlhdCI6MTU1OTIwMjYwOCwiZXhwIjoxODc0NTYyNjA4fQ.HEb3b6kpW6OzAxcLumS8DlJWmZVAWfn0Lg84seBZGpQ"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Content-Type", "application/json"));
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("entity_id", "script.gt11"));
Log.v("nameValue","entered");

try {
    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, HTTP.UTF_8));
```

The error I get is 401 Unauthorized on every attempt.

Answer (score 2):

I'm using Volley, but when I set up the headers, I do it with this:

```
HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String authValue = "Bearer " + apiToken;
    headers.put("Authorization", authValue);
    headers.put("Accept", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 2):

The "Authorization" should not be a parameter. Its a header.

> ```
> HttpPost request = new HttpPost(URL_SECURED_BY_BASIC_AUTHENTICATION);
> String auth = DEFAULT_USER + ":" + DEFAULT_PASS;
> byte[] encodedAuth = Base64.encodeBase64(
>   auth.getBytes(StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1));
> String authHeader = "Basic " + new String(encodedAuth);
> request.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
>
> HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
> HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
> ```

Comment: I'm passing a token... there are no credentials

Comment: Then just replace the new String(encodedAuth) with your token.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [OK Http](https://square.github.io/okhttp/) for networking requests? Then you can do something like this:

```
        val request = Request.Builder()
                .url(yourUrl)
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer $yourToken")
                .post(yourBody)
                .build()
```

Comment: Cause I'm using Apache which is built in